# LINQ - select from db and compare two lists

Tags: c#, linq

I am new to linq and I am writing a process which I believe can be improved.

To make it simple :
   I get a list of objects.
   I check in a db table which object has a row in the database.
   I return a list of objects with aditional boolean exists/not exists.

I have the following simple POCO

```
public class Project  
{
   public Guid? Id {get; set;}
   public string name {get; set;}
}
```

Notice not always I have an id and therefor I should skip this object.
(strange but this is only very close to my requirement in reallife)

Here is my Code - need improvement:

```
// Get List OF Project Guids
List<Project> ProjectList = GetProjects()
IEnumerable<Guid?> projectsIDs = from package in packages select package.Key;
List<Guid?> prjGuidsList = projectsIDs.ToList();

// Sends the list of Guids and return only the one that exists in the db
// will be implemented with select.. where.. in..
List<Guid?> dbProjects = FilterSharedVersions(prjGuidsList);


// create a new object that will contain the true false value
List<ProjectsToken> tokens = packages.Select(subject => new ProjectsToken
 {
  Id = subject.id
  MetaKey = subject.Name,
  exists = dbProjects.contains(subjecy.id)
 }    
).ToList();

return tokens;
```

Answer (score 3):

The [Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/bhkz42b3.aspx) method of the List class will perform very poorly in O(n). You need to build a HashSet instead, then the method [Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356440.aspx) will perform in O(1).

```
var dbProjects = new HashSet<Guid?>(FilterSharedVersions(prjGuidsList));
var tokens = packages.Select(subject => new ProjectsToken
 {
     Id = subject.id
     MetaKey = subject.Name,
     exists = dbProjects.Contains(subjecy.id)
 }    
).ToList();
```

Comment: @rails : I don't see any question, so I tried as hard as I can to help you :)